# I would like some feedback on my first suggested edit reviews

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I recently reached 2k reputation and gained the privilege to edit and review suggested edits.  I wanted a bit of guidance one whether my first few reviews are appropriate.  Specifically, I want to know if I'm being too harsh on [this Reject and Edit decision](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293198).  I thought that this edit just wasn't comprehensive enough and missed some fixable grammar issues.

Also, I noticed that when I clicked <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd> my edit immediately rejected and supplanted the suggested one.  Are there any other "gotchas" like this I should be aware of?

Some of my other reviews:

- [Reject and edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293374)
- [Approve](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293369)
- [Reject](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293727)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables It finally loaded for me, screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aaV9i.png. Seems to be working now.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's break 'em down:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293198 - I could see this going either way.  The editor did fix a few typos, but didn't remove the thanks.  In my opinion, edits should fix as much as possible, and I'm curmudgeonly, so I'd vote to Reject and Edit; others may vote to Approve &  Edit with the "Improve Edit" option.
2. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293374 - This one is a train wreck.  [Edit #2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30597293/2) starts it off by at least adding a "Run code snippet" section, but introduces some terrible text (some of it from the OP, some of it their own).

   The suggested edit

   - introduces an unnecessary greeting,
   - *removes* the "Run code snippet" section.

   But it also fixes:

   - a lot of capitalizations of "I",
   - and also removes the "please help".

   I would probably "Reject and Edit" this one too, because of the unnecessary greeting and removing the "Run code snippet", but you ***also*** removed the "Run code snippet" section.

   *Always make sure you don't take away anything that would detract from the question.*
3. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293369 - it's a decent enough edit to be approved.
4. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293727 - absolutely should have been rejected; the bizarre changing of "Am" to "I m", and removing the entire code section, this should at a minimum have been Rejected, but I went ahead with "Reject and Edit", to immediately fix other issues with the question as well.

   That particular user actually had a string of bad edits, which I all Rejected and Edited, and then notified the user about by commenting in a question of theirs.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions.